# multiple(nested) ValueEventListeners not working in firebase realtime database for android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fatal-error

The project I'm working on has 3 "tables" in firebase realtime database namely:

Users(contains login information of the users e.g email, passwords mobile numbers etc)

VictimProfiles(Contains basic profile information like profile pic string, name, job title and the corresponding UserID from Users table)

VolunteerProfiles(contains the Address,latitude,longitude,availability timing and the corresponding UserID and VictimProfileID (the ones generated by Firebase))

in my Google Maps activity, I'm required to drop markers on the location of each volunteer as well as the user currently using the app, with a customized info window showing the necessary info on the volunteers,
however, as shown in the code below, when I try to access the VictimProfile and Users table from within the ValueEventListener of the volunteer table, their data does not get written to the  public strings I'm writing it to. I know it sounds convoluted, but take a look at the code and you'll see what I mean

```
    public void DropVolunteerMarkers()
    {
        //DROP ALL MARKERS FUNCTION
        volunteerDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot volunteerprofile:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {

                    key=(String) volunteerprofile.child("UserID").getValue();
                    victimID=(String) volunteerprofile.child("VictimProfileID").getValue();
                    getVictimInfo();//GET NAME,PIC,JOB TITLE FROM THE VICTIM TABLE FOR THIS SPECIFIC VOLUNTEER
                    getUserInfo();//GET EMAIL AND PHONE NUMBER FROM USERS TABLE FOR THIS SPECIFIC VOLUNTEER
                    String currentuserid=SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(FindNearbyVolunteers.this);
                    if(!key.equals(currentuserid))//TO AVOID CURRENT USER BEING SHOWN AS A VOLUNTEER
                    {
                        address= (String)volunteerprofile.child("Address").getValue();
                        availabiliity=(String)volunteerprofile.child("Availability").getValue();
                        String LAT= (String) volunteerprofile.child("Latitude").getValue();
                        String LNG= (String) volunteerprofile.child("Longitude").getValue();
                        Toast.makeText(FindNearbyVolunteers.this,LAT+", "+LNG,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Double Lat= Double.parseDouble(LAT);
                        Double Long= Double.parseDouble(LNG);
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Lat,Long);
                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        Toast.makeText(FindNearbyVolunteers.this,key+", "+victimID+", "+name+", "+jobtitle+", "+availabiliity+", "+email+", "+address,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        //mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new VolunteerPopupAdapter(FindNearbyVolunteers.this,name,jobtitle,availabiliity,email,address,dp,number));
                        markerOptions.title(volunteerprofile.getKey().toString());
                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                    }
                    else{
                        //IN CASE OF CURRENT USER
                            //Place current location marker
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                            markerOptions.position(latLng);
                            markerOptions.title("YOU");
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
                            mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }}

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

the getVictimInfo() method:

```
 private void getVictimInfo()
    {
        victimDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot victimProfile:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    if(victimProfile.getKey().equals(victimID))
                    {
                        dp=(String)victimProfile.child("DP").getValue();
                        jobtitle=(String)victimProfile.child("JobTitle").getValue();
                        name=(String)victimProfile.child("Name").getValue();

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

the getUserInfo() method

```
        private void getUserInfo(){
        userDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot userProfile:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    if(userProfile.getKey().equals(key))
                    {
                        email=(String)userProfile.child("Email").getValue();
                        number=(String)userProfile.child("Mobile").getValue();;

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

the string where I'm supposed to save the values

```
 DatabaseReference volunteerDatabaseReference,userDatabaseReference,victimDatabaseReference;
String dp,jobtitle="no value",name="no value";
String email="no value",number="no value",address="no value",availabiliity="no value",victimID,key;
```

my Database screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXIIe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use something now that hasn't been loaded yet. With other words, you cannot simply declare `dp`, `jobtitle` and `email` as global variable and use them outside the `onDataChange()` method because it will always be `null` due the asynchronous behaviour of this method. This means that by the time you are trying to use those values outside that method, the data hasn't finished loading yet from the database and that's why is not accessible and you are always getting `null` and that's why nothing is written in your database.

A quick solve for this problem would be to all those values only inside the `onDataChange()` method, or if you want to use them outside, I recommend you dive into the asynchronous world and see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: thanks, I wouldn't have thought of that!! I'll look into it and try a different method. much appreciated!

Comment: Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: it makes sense, so yeah. Gave me  a new direction ti think in.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm stuck again. I tried putting all the database calls in separate, independent functions, where data is fetched into local variables and THEN into global Lists, but the problem persists. only the first call to the database works, the others are not even started. I tried this as a workaround to the asynchronous problem (trying to sequentialize my DB calls instead of trying to jump between them). any ideas?

Comment: Use the data that you are getting from the database only inside `onDataChange()` method. Add all your logic there.